# Як навчитися розмовної українській мові?

Tags: фонетика

Чи є електронні курси української мови які можуть навчити правильної вимови ?

Comment: https://eventukraine.com/success/5-bezkoshtovnih-onlajn-resursiv-dlya-vivchennya-ukrainskoi/

Comment: Це не лише курси (і, мабуть, здебільшого не курси), але там безліч різних посилань: https://speakukraine.net/.

Comment: Якщо конкретно щодо вимови (фонетики/орфоепії, а лексику й граматику Ви знаєте), то багатьом подобається [Микола Погрібний «Українська літературна вимова»](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUrx793sn2I).

Comment: Спасибі велике всім хто відповів. Мене цікавить правильна вимова.  Микола Погрібний може допомогти. Але я поки не можу знайти текст цієї книги.

Comment: А чому тут всі відповідають в коментарях? Це суперечить правилам спільноти. Зробімо з коментарів вікі-статтю і буде вже ближче до наших стандартів?

Comment: Починайте з байок Леоніда Глібова і далі ласуйте «Енеїдою» Івана Котляревського.

Answer (score 1):

Найкращим способом буде практикуватись з мовцем української. Однак, серед інтернету я можу виділити наступні ресурси:

1. E-language http://emova.language-ua.online/
2. The official site of the Ukrainian language https://ukrainskamova.com/
3. LanguageTool:spelling service https://languagetool.org/uk/
4. Info http://www.mova.info/
5. Online courses «Lifehackes in Ukrainian» https://ukr-lifehacks.ed-era.com/
6. Free courses of the Ukrainian Language https://web.archive.org/web/20190925095657/http://movaua.org.ua/

Comment: А Є-мова - точно живий проект? У них жодна з лінок "реєстрація", "тестування", "навчання", "сертифікат" не веде куди треба.

Comment: "movaua" веде на якесь "Joycasino"

Comment: Про всяк випадок повернув посилання на архівну версію movaua — можливо, організація ще діє, але про свій сайт не дбає, хоча хтозна…

Comment: Національна платформа з вивчення української мови Міністерства культури та інформаційної політики України  https://speakukraine.net/